# Converting cURL request to Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to turn this cURL request into a Python code. I want to eventually be able to save this to a CSV file but I need to get connected first.

```
curl --compressed -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'X-Api-Key: 123abc' 'https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v2/data/trades.v1/exchanges/cbse/spot/btc-usd/aggregations/count_ohlcv_vwap?interval=1h'
```

I started with this:

```
import requests
import json

key='api-key'

url = 'https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v2/data/trades.v1/exchanges/'
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = (key)

headers = {
   *not sure how to do this*
}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The docs say this needs to be in the header:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip:
```

How do I include the API key? how do I save the data once its returned?

Comment: What about starting from [the documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/)?

Comment: You could just put the curl request in a subprocess.check_output command and go from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`X-Api-Key` would be a request header, so you can include it in your headers variable, like this:

```
headers = {
   "X-Api-Key": key,
   "Accept": "application/json",
   "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
}
```

(took the others ones from your current curl request)

You can get the data by using `r.text`, like this:

```
print(r.text)
```

Your code should look like this:

```
import requests
import json

key='api-key'

url = 'https://us.market-api.kaiko.io/v2/data/trades.v1/exchanges/'

headers = {
   "X-Api-Key": key,
   "Accept": "application/json",
   "Accept-Encoding": "gzip"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(r.text)
```

If you want to get a json object instead, you can use `r.json()`